# Soundcard Driver HP x2 Detatchable

Tags: drivers, sound, soundcard

So, after searching the forums and re-downloading packages and even completely reinstalling ubuntu, I cannot get my soundcard to be identified. I have a HP x2 Detachable 2 in 1 tablet/laptop. Is there any way I could put in a request for a driver to be coded to work with ubuntu? I really love linux and it works flawlessly on my other computers and I really don't want to have to switch back to windows 10 for my primary laptop's OS.